# Decision tree that can provide two predictions as output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, prediction, decision-tree

**Backstory:** I am currently working on a multi-label (153 labels) classification problem, and I am being asked for (what seems to be) a pretty unique output feature. My customer wants a predicted value for a new observation (pretty standard), as well as a "second guess" as a backup measure. I've never heard of this before and am not finding anything about generating such a metric through SO or google.

If my model's confidence in the prediction is below a certain percentage, the prediction will be hand checked to ensure accuracy, and my customer would like two have two predictions on hand so they can quickly look to those specifications and see if they match in the hopes of reducing the time needed for manual validation.

**Request:** Sadly I don't have any code of what I've tried so far because I don't even know where I'd start. I feel like some kind of 'if x IS NOT x, then' loop action would occur, but I just don't know.

**Desired output:** Just an example of what what my desired output file would look like would be something like this:

```
Actual label | Predicted Label | confidence | second guess | confidence
      1               1             .85             2           .09
      2               2             .51             2           .34
      3               27            .22             3           .21
```

Formatting the output is something I can handle on my own, but the last two columns are what I'm not able to generate at this time. If someone could merely point me in the direction of some documentation or an example of this being done, I'm willing to do the research and apply it to my specific use-case on my own.

thanks :)

Comment: @ChrisA Thank you for offering this solution. The output values are integer values, whereas I would have thought they'd be decimal. If the predictions from my first test observation are '53' and '126', does that imply 53% confidence in prediction one and 12.6% confidence in prediction two?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing looks quite a lot like the TOP-N measure, which measure the accuracy and accounts for a correct output if the ground truth is present among the N more likely outputs according to the model. I believe what you are looking for is this https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba which returns the probabilities of each of the samples on your test set belonging to each of the classes, all you have to do is sort and take the top N, in your case top 2

Comment: Something like `np.argsort(clf.predict_proba(X), axis=1)[:, -2:]`

Comment: thank you @Pablo Arnau González . I will need to review this and try to understand how I pull N number of predictions, but I'm sure I can figure it out. I will dig into this and report back

Comment: @ChrisA Thank you for offering this solution. The output values are integer values, whereas I would have thought they'd be decimal. If the predictions from my first test observation are '53' and '126', does that imply 53% confidence in prediction one and 12.6% confidence in prediction two?

Comment: The output values are the indices of your predicted labels, use these to index your classes

Comment: @ChrisA Oh, so the output in the first column (53) is the index of the first occurrence of that particular label within X_test, or just a random index of that particular label? So, if I go to row 53 of X_test and examine my target variable column, I will find the 'first predicted' label? and the second column is the index of the 'next best guess', yeah?

Comment: something has gone wrong if the first index is 53 and you only have 32 labels....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201272/discussion-between-nick-bohl-and-chris-a).